Are typescript interfaces extending a type multiple times prohibited?
I have the following situation:
declare namespace MySymbols {
    const foo: unique symbol
    const bar: unique symbol
}

type LogicSymbols = typeof MySymbols 

// wraps an object type so that for any key K of that object
// that is also a key of MySymbols 
// that symbol is added to the object so that
// obj[K] has the same type as obj[MySymbols[K]]
type WithSymbols<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T & {
    readonly [K in keyof (LogicSymbols | T) as LogicSymbols[K]]: T[K];
};

interface WithFooAndBar
    extends WithSymbols<{ foo: boolean; }>,
        WithSymbols<{ bar: boolean; }> {
}

declare let variable: WithFooAndBar;

let a = variable.foo; // rendered just fine
let b = variable.bar; // unresolved variable bar

IntelliJ tells me this cannot happen as it won't read the prop of the second extension: bar. Strangely this is fine within VScode (it will read bar just fine) and both use typescript 5.5.2.
My question: is this valid typescript? And if so, how do I get IntelliJ to read it properly? If not, how would I fix it?
Here is a link to the typescript playground with the code. Seems to run fine there as well.

Can you compile it outside of one of these editors, using TSC (TypeScriptCompiler)?

Yeah it compiles just fine on the CLI

This is definitely valid TypeScript. No idea what to say about intellij (so I'll disengage now)

Looks like this issue is fixed in the latest version. I can not replicate it in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2 EAP (Ultimate Edition),Build #IU-242.18071.24. Could you please test 2024.2 EAP and let us know if the issue is resolved?

First of all: thank you for pointing out versions, I am indeed running on an old version (2020.2.4) and forgot that could be relevant.
Within the EAP, I indeed cannot replicate the error. Another one shows up: when you hover on either foo or bar, you get let variable: WithFooAndBar. This seems to be the type-definition of the parent and not it's own type definition. I am unsure if this is intended behaviour, it differs from the behaviour in 2024.1 (where the definition of foo pops up correctly and bar has the same behaviour as in 2024.2).
